# Is there an automated way of fixing one line ifs in PHP?

Tags: php, code-cleanup

I don't know if it's just me or not, but I am allergic to one line ifs in any c like language, I always like to see curly brackets after an if, so instead of

```
if($a==1)
  $b = 2;
```

or

```
if($a==1) $b = 2;
```

I'd like to see

```
if($a==1){
   $b = 2; 
}
```

I guess I can support my preference by arguing that the first one is more prone to errors, and it has less readability.

My problem right now is that I'm working on a code that is packed with these one line ifs, I was wondering if there is some sort of utility that will help me correct these ifs, some sort of php code beautifier that would do this.

I was also thinking of developing some sort of regex that could be used with linux's sed command, to accomplish this, but I'm not sure if that's even possible given that the regex should match one line ifs, and wrap them with curley brackets, so the logic would be to find an if and the conditional statement, and then look for { following the condition, if not found then wrap the next line, or the next set of characters before a line break and then wrap it with { and }

What do you think?

Comment: If this is for code belonging to a team, consult with them before making any changes to the coding convention (unless the code is in violation of a written standards document)

Comment: Changing working code wholesale to match your preferences will not be useful to you or your team in the long run. If you find yourself working with code that doesn't fit your preferred style go ahead and change it (so long as such changes won't step on the toes of team members you haven't discussed it with), but don't go changing files unrelated to your current task for the sake of style alone.

Comment: I understand where your coming from (I always use curly braces), but I would be worried about parsing errors completely screwing up the code.  Personally, whenever I have to work with someone elses code (and they no longer are in charge of it), I go through manually and reformat everything to my liking. It takes time, but i get to read through and understand all the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP beautifiers (libraries for formatting code)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709184/php-beautifiers-libraries-for-formatting-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use the built-in PHP tokenizer, and to parse the resulting token stream.

See this answer for more information about the PHP Tokenizer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5642653/1005039

You can also take a look at a script I wrote to parse PHP source files to fix another common problem in legacy code, namely to fix unquoted array indexes:
https://github.com/GustavBertram/php-array-index-fixer/blob/master/aif.php

The script uses a state machine instead of a generalized parser, but in your case it might be good enough.