# PHP foreach, arrays data used in query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have:

```
$array1 =     //contains places ids and locations;
$array2 = array();
$array3 = array();


  foreach($array1 as $itemz)
  {     
      $array2[] = $itemz[place][id];
      $array3[] = $itemz[place][location][city];

      $sql = "select * from places where id=".$array2." and location=".$array3."";
  }
```

But when I print $sql I get:

```
  select * from places where id=12 and location=Array
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with the code?

Thanks!

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: I'm completely mystified as to how he/she got `id=12` when $array2 is an array.

Comment: SQL injection warning: use mysql_real_escape_string() to protect yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why using array when you only need a standard variable :

```
$array1 =     //contains places ids and locations;

foreach($array1 as $itemz)
{     
    $id = $itemz['place']['id'];
    $city = $itemz['place']['location']['city'];

    $sql = "select * from places where id='$id' and location='$city'";
}
```

Comment: Please please please, read JohnP answer just below, I didn't notice about the lack of the quotes in your code. This is important, you have some serious problems in your code. I've updated my code too.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry but your code doesn't make sense at all. I'm surprised that you're getting that result at all. Let's walk through it.

**Where are the quotes?**

```
$array2[] = $itemz[place][id];
$array3[] = $itemz[place][location][city];
```

You're missing quotes here, please add them

```
$array2[] = $itemz['place']['id'];
$array3[] = $itemz['place']['location']['city'];
```

**Array to String conversion**

```
$sql = "select * from places where id=".$array2." and location=".$array3."";
```

This statement shouldn't work for 2 reasons.

1. Assuming that `id` is a single field of INT and you have a bunch of INTs in `$array2` you still can't compare them without a MySQL `IN`.
2. You're converting from a PHP array to a string. That won't work.

Since you're running this in a loop `$array2[]` and `$array3[]` will continue to change and will grow.

So what you're actually trying to do is come up with a query like

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM places 
        WHERE 
             id IN (" . implode(',', $array2) . ") AND 
             location IN (" . implode(',', $array3) . ")";
```

But this makes no sense at all because as the loop continues you're retrieving the same data incrementally.

**So I think what you actually want to do is**

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM places 
        WHERE 
             id = {$itemz['place']['id']} AND 
             location = {$itemz['place']['location']['city']}";
```

This is most probably what you need. This retrieves the rows for each row as you iterate through you array.

A couple of improvements I would do is.

Run your query once after the looping is done so you only have to run the query one time and not `n` times.

Also, consider retrieving only the columns you need instead of doing `SELECT *`

Comment: I guess you mean `columns` instead of `rows` in your last sentence. Nevertheless +1.

Comment: @m42 columns indeed, fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use $array3 to build query, cause it is an array. Rather you can code like bellow -

```
 foreach($array1 as $i=>$itemz)
  {     
      $array2[$i] = $itemz[place][id];
      $array3[$i] = $itemz[place][location][city];

      $sql = "select * from places where id=".$array2[$i]." and location=".$array3[$i]."";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
 $array3[] = $itemz[place][location][city];
```

results in creating an array named `$array3` and adding an element equal to `$itemz[place][location][city]` with a key of `0` to it. When you try to embed this variable into the query you have a problem because it's not a string.

What you probably need is:

```
 $id = $itemz['place']['id'];
 $city = $itemz['place']['location']['city'];
 $sql = "select * from places where id=".intval($id)." and location='".
        mysql_real_escape_string($city)."'";
```

Notice that I have made changes to fix some other **serious** problems with the code ([indexing into arrays with constants instead of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5642197/50079) and [leaving your code vulnerable to SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)).